# Internet speed poor in Normal Mode, good in Safe Mode

Tags: speed, safe-mode, normal-mode

I am experiencing poor internet speed in Normal Mode and good internet speed in Safe Mode. Others have reported this as well, but in my case internet speed remains good when rebooting into Normal Mode after Safe Mode. Then gets slower some time later. Any suggestions how to figure out what is causing the slowdown?

Comment: You mean Safe Mode with Network, right?

Answer (score 0):

When in safe mode, your computer loads the minimum drivers necessary to allow system access, along with a few other features such as networking. Any other programs that would start in normal mode are not loaded.

You can perform a systematic manual culling of the programs in order to narrow the troublesome application.

I've used msconfig for systems older than Windows 10, selectively un-ticking the programs running in the StartUp tab, also matching the same names in the Services tab, then re-booting to run the testing. For Windows 10, the capability also exists in the Task Manager to disable starting software.

The concern in your case would be the "some time later" aspect of the slowing. It would require patience on your part to make use of the computer while partially configured, to determine if it will begin to slow again.